# Powershell, automatically add "\" before certain characters

Tags: powershell, regex

I wrote a script that grabs each line in a .txt file, one line at a time, and before moving on to grab the next line, an action is performed. Let's say this is the text file:

```
[Foo]
(Bar)
```

To make it more simple to understand, let's say this is what my script does:

```
Reads the first line in the text file and sets the line as $currentLine; [Foo]
Echo the $currentLine; [Foo]
Reads the next line in the text file and sets the line as $currentLine; (Bar)
Echo the $currentLine; (Bar)
```

My problem is I that I need `"[Foo]"` to be `"\[Foo\]"` and `"(Bar)"` to be `"\(Bar\)"` to correctly use the lines in my *actual* script. Is there an efficient way to do this? Or do I need to write something that checks for `"("`, `")"`, `"["`, and `"]"` then replaces them with `"\("`, `"\)"`, `"\["`, and `"\]"`?

Comment: The question is a bit hard to follow.  Are you saying that you want to use the strings as literals, including any parentheses characters?  Can you add the relevant part of your script so that we can see what you're currently doing with it?

Comment: Please excuse the vagueness, as I was only trying to reduce the complexity of the question. I am using the following line to select every file in a folder that contains "(Bar)" in the name, and replace "(Bar)" with "(USA)". The line I'm using for this is:
`get-childItem *"(Bar)"* | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace '\(Bar\)','(USA)' }`
The goal is to have "$myLine = (Bar)" to use "$myLine" in the line above. Because "$myLine" changes frequently to entries such as "(Foo)" and "[Bar]", I'm looking for the most efficient way to convert these entries to "\(Foo\)", "\[Bar\]", ect, to work.

Comment: Your example & further info is very helpful, but I can't tell if soandos' answer satisfies the situation.  For example, if it is just to accomplish replacing that part of the filenames, I'd probably resort to "ren" instead of scripting this way.

Comment: Using only "ren" without the -replace flag makes it very difficult to replace only _part_ of a filename. I think the solution here is to write an _if_ statement that checks for characters "( ) [ ]" and places a "\" in front of them if present. soandos's answer is relevant and for that I've upvoted it, as it may help others. For this case, though, I believe I'd have to write 4 separate "Replace" lines as soandos has suggested - one per character I need checked. I will be better off grouping the characters in an _if_ statement that will check for characters and proceed renaming accordingly. Ty!

Comment: *Further, the reason I can't simply use "ren" is the due to the fact that "(Bar)" is always located at the end of the filename. The proceeding characters in the filename are always different and have no pattern to them. Using -replace helps me to ignore the majority of the filename and continue on to selecting/replacing only the section I'm looking for, "(Bar)".

Comment: I use "ren" all the time this way.  i.e. "REN *(BAR).* *(USA).*" will do what is required.  I think it may be unobvious that you can easily wildcard renames. You can also use "?" in the filespec to signify a single character wildcard.

Comment: I have put the syntax for using REN in an answer, so that you can see the exact structure, since it doesn't render correctly in comments.  But you can use REN in many ways with partial filenames and wildcards, as I've shown.  This seems to be functionality  that many don't realize is available in the command.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell (and I'm not at all sure that I can tell correctly) you are looking for the `.replace` function.

As an example, one can do the following:

```
$a = "(bob)"
$a.Replace('(',"\(")
```

Returns `\(bob`

All replacements can be done this way

Answer (score 0):

I cannot put this in a comment without having characters replaced, so I'm putting it in an answer.  I use "ren" all the time as I've commented.  i.e.  `"REN *(BAR).* *(USA).*"` will do what is required.  I think it may be unobvious that you can easily wildcard renames. You can also use "?" in the filespec to signify a single character wildcard.